# Issue in time-stamp date in php

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp

I am having trouble in the timestamp.

When I am using the LAMP in Ubuntu, then it works with correct date which I entered, but on other systems it show 1 day back's date.

I don't know what I need to do now. I have stored the timestamp in my database. But when I am showing it on my web application, it works fine in the LAMP but not in others.

When I am converting the timezone to online converter it shows backdated result. What do I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set PHP default timezone before reading the date from the timestamp.

Add the following line before reading the date.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
```

Let me know if this helps.

References:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

Answer (score 1):

The timestamp stored is correct, Please set the default time zone in your PHP application to let the system know which timezone you are using then it will store the correct time zone. the below link would help you.

I am assuming you are storing timestamp in DB and retrieving it to display

http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but the thing is it works fine in my LAMP. I have used  date.timezone = "Asia/Kolkata" in both lamp and xampp system

Comment: is default time zone set in php.ini.. anyways setting default timezone probably solve your issue.

Comment: Thaks but it is showing correct in LAMP. But I am using date_default_timezone_set('UTC');  in LAMP system it shows same like xampp. But the thing is I need the date which is showing on LAMP system without set it UTC

Comment: it will consider the default timezone if you do not set it. to make your output similar on all systems you set explicitly in your application and it will work as expected..